# FFMPEG: seeking using a txt file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 40 videos that I need to trim, so they would start at the 6th second and then combine them into a single video.
I also have a `list_of_movies.txt` that contains the name of all the files I need to trim.

This is my problem:
When concatenating the videos to a single file, ffmpeg accepts:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list_of_movies.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

but when trimming, it would not accept:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:06 -i list_of_movies.txt trimmed .mp4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trim each video to start from its 6th second, you'll have to specify it for each file within the text file, so

```
file first.mp4
inpoint 5
file second.mp4
inpoint 5
file third.mp4
inpoint 5
[...]
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list_of_movies.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

However, in `copy` mode, ffmpeg can only extract, starting at a video keyframe, so expect extra frames and maybe broken audio sync.

It's best to re-encode,

```
ffmpeg -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -i list_of_movies.txt -vf select=concatdec_select,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -af aselect=concatdec_select,asetpts=N/SR/TB output.mp4
```

Comment: I've tried the re-encode, as suggested but i get the error below:
[Parsed_aselect_0 @ 000001c1a40ce000] [Eval @ 00000084f25fe3d0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'concatdec'
[Parsed_aselect_0 @ 000001c1a40ce000] Error while parsing expression 'concatdec'
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001c1a4028c00] Error initializing filter 'aselect' with args 'concatdec'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!